# SQL Query to parse one column data into several columns using delimiter

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I need a sql query that will allow me to split a single column into multiple columns.
For example:
Dataset 1 = "10.11.5-None-bobadmin:501 -1-1-87-PASS-11.1.0.9900-true"
Would be delimited in to separate columns based on the "-" character.
Data set would return the following

```
Col1    Col2    Col3    Col4    Col5    Col6    Col7    Col8    Col9
10.11.5 None    bobadmin:501    1   1   87  PASS    11.1.0.9900 TRUE
```

Any and all assistance is greatly appreciated!

Using SQL Server 2008R2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the sample below, I have 9 positions, but it is easily expanded into as many as you need

```
Declare @YourTable table (ID int,DataSet1 varchar(100))
Insert Into @YourTable values
(1,'10.11.5-None-bobadmin:501 -1-1-87-PASS-11.1.0.9900-true'),
(2,'10.11.6-All-JaneAdmin:999 -9-9-99-FAIL-12.2.2.555-false')

Select A.ID
      ,B.*
 From  @YourTable A
 Cross Apply (
                Select Col1 = xDim.value('/x[1]','varchar(max)')
                      ,Col2 = xDim.value('/x[2]','varchar(max)')
                      ,Col3 = xDim.value('/x[3]','varchar(max)')
                      ,Col4 = xDim.value('/x[4]','varchar(max)')
                      ,Col5 = xDim.value('/x[5]','varchar(max)')
                      ,Col6 = xDim.value('/x[6]','varchar(max)')
                      ,Col7 = xDim.value('/x[7]','varchar(max)')
                      ,Col8 = xDim.value('/x[8]','varchar(max)')
                      ,Col9 = xDim.value('/x[9]','varchar(max)')
                 From (Select Cast('<x>' + Replace(A.DataSet1,'-','</x><x>')+'</x>' as XML) as xDim) A
             ) B
```

Returns

[image]

> **EDIT**

Or if you want a UDF

```
Select * from [dbo].[udf-Str-Parse-Row]('10.11.5-None-bobadmin:501 -1-1-87-PASS-11.1.0.9900-true','-')
```

Returns

[image]

The UDF if needed

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[udf-Str-Parse-Row] (@String varchar(max),@Delimiter varchar(10))
Returns Table 
As
Return (
    Select Pos1 = xDim.value('/x[1]','varchar(max)')
          ,Pos2 = xDim.value('/x[2]','varchar(max)')
          ,Pos3 = xDim.value('/x[3]','varchar(max)')
          ,Pos4 = xDim.value('/x[4]','varchar(max)')
          ,Pos5 = xDim.value('/x[5]','varchar(max)')
          ,Pos6 = xDim.value('/x[6]','varchar(max)')
          ,Pos7 = xDim.value('/x[7]','varchar(max)')
          ,Pos8 = xDim.value('/x[8]','varchar(max)')
          ,Pos9 = xDim.value('/x[9]','varchar(max)')
     From (Select Cast('<x>' + Replace(@String,@Delimiter,'</x><x>')+'</x>' as XML) as xDim) A
)
--Select * from [dbo].[udf-Str-Parse-Row]('Dog,Cat,House,Car',',')
```

Comment: Thank you very much!  Your first solution works well.

Comment: I will also test the second to see what gives th ebest performance.
Thanks Again!

Comment: @user3170410 The first will give slightly better performance.  The second is just for convenience.